# Module build failed: Error: read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, linux, laravel, npm, vuejs2

I have no idea what to do with these errors. It happens when I'm deploying my laravel website to the server and run `npm run dev`. On my local machine I do not have this errors so I'm totally confused =(

I'm using:
Debian@8.9
nodejs@8.9.4
npm@5.6.0
laravel@5.4
vuejs@2.3.3

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 5 errors                                                         

 error  in ./resources/assets/images/bg-welcome.jpg

Module build failed: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:615:25)

 @ ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-127c868a"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./resources/assets/js/views/Home.vue 222:13-51 234:13-51
 @ ./resources/assets/js/views/Home.vue
 @ ./resources/assets/js/routes.js
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/images/posters/2.jpg

Module build failed: Error: Command failed: /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg
/var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/mozjpeg/vendor/cjpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


    at Promise.all.then.arr (/var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/imagemin-mozjpeg/node_modules/execa/index.js:236:11)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

 @ ./~/vue-loader/lib/template-compiler?{"id":"data-v-2ac4f506"}!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./resources/assets/js/views/client/MyTracks.vue 124:13-53
 @ ./resources/assets/js/views/client/MyTracks.vue
 @ ./resources/assets/js/routes.js
 @ ./resources/assets/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/img/bg-welcome.jpg

Module build failed: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:615:25)

 @ ./~/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false}!./~/postcss-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 4:249600-249632
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/img/bg-welcome-clean.jpg

Module build failed: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:615:25)

 @ ./~/css-loader?{"url":true,"sourceMap":false}!./~/postcss-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./~/resolve-url-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"precision":8,"outputStyle":"expanded","sourceMap":true}!./resources/assets/sass/app.scss 4:284816-284854
 @ ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss
 @ multi ./resources/assets/js/app.js ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

 error  in ./resources/assets/sass/app.scss

Module build failed: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: Error: read ECONNRESET
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Pipe.onread (net.js:615:25)
    at runLoaders (/var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:192:19)
    at /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:364:11
    at /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:230:18
    at context.callback (/var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at /var/www/www-root/data/www/domain.com/releases/20180212002544/node_modules/img-loader/index.js:45:31
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: I've been getting this intermittently on a dojo build process for a while (ubuntu@16.04.3, nodejs@8.9.4, npm@5.6.0). Definitely not related to vue.js. I suspect it has to do with Node's file handling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are using `image-webpack-loader` version `4.x` right?.

If so, I am afraid you need to revert back to 3.6.0 for now.